# Python Objects and Lists within Dictionary

Tags: python, json

I'm pretty new to Python, so just working my way through understanding the data sets.

I'm having a little trouble producing the JSON output that is required for the API I am working with.

I am using

```
import json
json.load(data_file)
```

Working with Python dictionary and then doing

```
json.dump(dict, json_data)
```

My data needs to look like the following when it is output.

```
    {
  "event":{
    "id":10006,
    "event_name":"My Event Name",
  },
  "sub event":[

  ],
  "attendees":[
    {
      "id":11201,
      "first_name":"Jeff",
      "last_name":"Smith",
    },
    {
      "id":10002,
      "first_name":"Victoria",
      "last_name":"Baker",
    },
  ]
}
```

I have been able to create the arrays in python and dump to json, but I am having difficulty creating the event "object" in the dictionary. I am using the below:

```
attendees = ['attendees']
attendeesdict = {}
attendeesdict['first_name'] = "Jeff"
attendees.append(attendeesdict.copy())
```

Can anyone help me add the "event" object properly?

Comment: You're having difficulty with the Event object/dcit but your question seems to be about the *Attendees* dict. Please clarify. You probably will not be able to use `.copy` method here if done inside a loop, but you need to show more code so we can understand what you're actually attempting to implement, and how you're going abou it.

Comment: The code you have so far makes no sense anyway. There is no need to have the string `'attendees'` as the first element in the attendees list.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking for. What is in you "data_file" ? please post its content. Your event seems to be a very simple dictionary so what is stopping you from doing a simple `json_data["event"] = { "id":10006, "event_name":"My Event Name" }` ? You will notice that Python dict/list and JSON are very much look-alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, going from JSON to dictionary is almost no work because the two are very similar, if not identical:

```
attendees = [
    {
        "first_name": "Jeff"
        # Add other fields which you need here
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Victoria"
    }    
]
```

In this instance, `attendees` is a list of dictionaries. For the `event`:

```
event = {
    "id": 10006,
    "event_name": "My Event Name"
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
data = {
    "event": event,
    "sub event": [],
    "attendees": attendees
}
```

Now, you can convert it to a JSON object, ready to send to your API:

```
json_object = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This explained it perfectly for me, I was making things so overcomplicated by iterating through all the lists, python makes it so simple when you see it like this!

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to statically create a nested dict, you can use a single literal. If you paste the JSON above into python code, you would get a valid dict literal.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have built all the values elsewhere and now you're just putting them together:

```
result = {'event':event_dict, 'sub event':subevent_list, 'attendees':attendees_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct your `dicts` and add like below

```
    {
      "event":"add your dict"
      "sub event":["add your dict"],
      "attendees":["add your dict"]
    }
```